# Отправка переменной PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Есть страница.
На нее выводится информация echo `"$catalogVars['goodsDesc']";`
Необходимо отправить эту переменную в некоторый скрипт `script.php`
Был написан следующий javascript.

```
function set_description() {
var text_prdct = "<?=$catalogVars['goodsDesc']?>";
jQuery.ajax({
      url:'/forma/desc_prdct.php'
      , type:'POST'
      , data:{name: "<?=$catalogVars['goodsDesc']?>"  }
      , success: function(response) {
      document.write(response); 
     }
  });
}
```

Обычные строки он отправляет.
Однако возникла следующая проблема.
Содержание переменной

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
<img alt="Стенд и картинки для уголка безопасности" border="0" src="/images/goods/umey_deystvovat.jpg" title="Стенд и картинки для уголка безопасности" /></div><div style="text-align: center;"><div style="text-align: center;">
    <img alt="Пожарная безопасность в школе" border="0" src="/images/goods/pb_foto_2.jpg" title="Пожарная безопасность в школе" /></div>
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <br />
    Пожарная безопасность в школе<br />
    &nbsp;</div>
<p style="text-align: justify">
    Пожар всегда был и остается большой опасностью. А дети в несколько раз чаще взрослых становятся жертвами огня. Каждому ребенку необходимо знать, что делать в случае возгорания, поэтому в школе необходим уголок, посвященный действиям при пожаре, должны проводиться специальные занятия. Информационный школьный стенд с картинками &laquo;Умей действовать при пожаре&raquo; прекрасно подойдет для оформления уголка пожарной безопасности, кабинета ОБЖ в школе, а также на роль инструмента для обучающих игр на тему пожарной безопасности. Форма и яркие цвета стенда будут привлекать внимание детей к информации, способствовать ее запоминанию. <br />
    <br />
    В цену стенда входит комплект ламинированных картинок по безопасности <a href="/posters/pojar.html">Умей действовать при пожаре</a> 10пл.</p>
```

Содержание переменной всегда разное. Если не заэкранировать кавычки функция - неопределена, при наличии угольных скобок var_dump показывает пустую строку.

Comment: Как вариант можно сохранить переменную в сессию

Comment: Может будет проще отправить ID данного каталога или к чему там привязано ваше описание, и уже в script.php достать это самое описание?

Comment: в этом то и проблема идентификаторов нет.

Comment: закодируйте строку в base64 и в script.php раскодируйте)

Comment: не могу переменной яваскрипт дать значение переменной пхп. экранировать пробовал - не помогает.

Comment: что значит не можете? data:{name: "<?=base64_encode($catalogVars['goodsDesc'])?>"  }

Comment: сработало. Но нашел другое решение. Сделал для каждой переменной  php див с id в html и поместил содержимое php-переменных в этот див, сделал диву display:none -  и беру из дива значения var helper = $('#helper').html();

Answer (score 2):

А если попробовать

```
var text_prdct = '<?php echo strtr(addslashes($catalogVars['goodsDesc']),"\n",null);?>';
```

Тут нужно использовать одинарные кавычки, предварительно экранизировав их в данных, а также, как минимум, удалить переносы строк из данных.